# subdomain wildcard .htaccess for escape cloudflare

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard, cloudflare

I have `example.com` domain and set on cloudflare.
But some time I don't need to use cloudflare, so I create `up.example.com` subdomain and unused of cloudflare for it. then I park it on main domain.
That means the `example.com` and `up.example.com` point to root site.
Now for cover duplicate content in SEO, I need to a `.htaccess` file.

These items is important for me:

- All URLs under main domain (example.com) must be open and accessible.
- The main page don't open with subdomain (up.example.com) and just open with main domain (example.com).
- All address with `upload` controller must be accessible from subdomain. for example: up.example.com/upload/
- The word after controller (my action) just is contain a-z, 0-9 (because don't allow use dot for point to a file)
- About another URLs path must don't accessible from subdomain and must get 404 error.

For this, I write a code here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\..+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/upload/?[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L,NS]

# Hide index.php , this used for YII PHP Framework
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

But in this code my problem is:

- up.example.com => open it! but don't must open it.
- up.example.com/upload/test => get me `Not Found. The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.` , but must open it.

Note: about another URLs I get correct 404 error, for example for up.example.com/upload/test.jpg I get `Not Found. The requested URL /upload/test.jpg was not found on this server.` error message, in this error message pointed exactly to `/upload/test.jpg` but about `up.example.com/upload/test` in error message pointed to `index.php` file!

Please assist me to have correction `.htaccess` code.

Comment: Reason why this question remains unanswered is that there are too many requirements clubbed in one question. Try to simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem with help in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26437130/1407491).
Just must use `!^index\.php$` instead `.`

correction code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [R=404,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/upload/?[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ - [R=404,L,NC]

# Hide index.php , this used for YII PHP Framework
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```