# wildcard .htaccess and reject some address on subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want all file or directory existed under `up.example.com` subdomain rejected and show 404 error.

Also I want all another request point to `index.php`.

I write this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

When I test this code for `http://up.example.com/test.jpg`

If `test.jpg` file existed on root server, show me this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /test.jpg was not found on this server.
Apache Server at up.example.com Port 80
```

It's ok!
But when `test.jpg` not existed, give me this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
Apache Server at up.example.com Port 80
```

Instead open `index.php` (`index.php` exist on root)

Why? and how can I fix it?

Comment: The first set of rules is not ok. It combines AND between first two RewriteCond (default) and OR to the third one. Also  you have to add there exclusion of index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that you write everything to `index.php` and that becomes a valid file in the request. When `mod_rewrite` runs next time first rule sends it to 404.

To overcome this error have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if it is valid file or directory except for index.php
# then send 404 to browser
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [R=404,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ - [R=404,L,NC]

# send all non-file/directories to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Are sure that the first rule will not be fired when directory exists, but host does not start with `up.`? `condition1 AND condition2 OR condition3` works even when only `condition3` is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, now I have other problem, that's the `http://up.example.com/index.php` url open.

Comment: ok what is the problem when you enter `http://up.example.com/index.php` in browser?

Comment: @anubhava, Thanks alot, worked now! Before it, I working on this issue about 1 week :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\.(.+)$ [NC]  # remove if it is not related to subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^up\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NS]
```